# how to select a url from database column with array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to get a url from an url array created from db but my array seems empty.How should i get any url from db table's url column.

```
    $dbc = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname) or die('connect failed');
    $r= mysqli_query ($dbc, "select url from urllist ")or die('query failed');

     $url = array();

while($set = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
    $url[] = $set['url'];
}
echo $url[5];
```

Comment: connected with `mysqli` fetches with `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/12860140

Comment: then what should i do ? if i use  without msqli nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var_dump($url);` to inspect your variable contents.
You might be trying to access a non-existent index!

Try the following code:

**OO Style**

```
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname);
$res = $con->query('SELECT url FROM urllist');
$url = [];

while($row = $res->fetch_array())
{
    $url[] = $row['url'];
}

var_dump($url);
```

**Procedural Style**

```
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname);
$res = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT url FROM urllist');
$url = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

var_dump($url);
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: thats what i was looking for thanks.this is object oriented style so we can solve with procedural style ?

Comment: Yes, of course! I'll update with a procedural style, just a minute.